# Zero Cohomology means zero homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose we have a space $X$, which has zero cohomology (except in degree zero). Does he neccesarly have zero homology (except in degree zero)?

If not, what if $X$ is a manifold?

Universal Coefficient theorem gives me, that $Hom(H_*(X),\mathbb{Z})$ vanishes, but this isn't enough to conclude, that $H_*(X)$ vanishes, right?

Comment: The universal coefficient theorem gives you a short exact sequence with $H^*(X)$ in the middle. What happens to other terms?

Comment: These are $Ext(H_{*-1}(X),\mathbb{Z})$ and $Hom(H_{*}(X),\mathbb{Z})$ and if $H^*(X)$ is zero, of course they are zero too.

Comment: But why should that mean, that $H_*(X)$ is zero?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$We can assume $X$ path-connected, by restricting to each path-component.

Then yes, vanishing cohomology does imply vanishing homology. In Hatcher's *Algebraic topology*, proposition 3F.12, it is proven that $\tilde{H}^*(X) = 0$ implies that $\tilde{H}_n(X)$ is finitely generated for all $n$, because otherwise $H^*(X)$ would be uncountable.

Now the universal coefficient theorem tells you that for every $n > 0$, $$\begin{align}
\hom(H_n(X), \Z) & = 0
& \mathrm{Ext}(H_n(X), \Z) & = 0
\end{align}$$

But since $H_n(X)$ is a finitely generated abelian group, you can write it as
$$H_n(X) = \Z^r \oplus \Z/p_1^{\alpha_1} \oplus \dots \oplus \Z/p_s^{\alpha_s}$$

- The first equation gives you $\hom(H_n(X), \Z) \simeq \Z^r = 0 \Rightarrow r = 0$;
- The second equation gives you $\mathrm{Ext}(H_n(X), \Z) \simeq \Z/p_1^{\alpha_1} \oplus \dots \oplus \Z/p_s^{\alpha_s} = 0 \Rightarrow s = 0$.

Therefore $H_n(X) = 0$.